# Why does closing a nested child dialog also close the parent dialog?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, showdialog

I open a form as a modal dialog using ShowDialog. This dialog in turn allows another form to be opened as a modal dialog again using ShowDialog.

When the innermost dialog is closed, this causes its parent dialog to close as well. Why does this occur and how can I prevent it?

I have created a hello world version of the problem to illustrate this.

Form 1:

[image: Form 1]

```
private void OpenForm2Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 testForm = new Form2();
    DialogResult dialogResult = new DialogResult();
    dialogResult = testForm.ShowDialog();
    MessageBox.Show("Form 2 returned: " + Convert.ToString(dialogResult));
}
```

Form 2:

[image: Form 2]

```
...
this.Form2OKButton.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
this.Form2CancelButton.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
...
this.AcceptButton = this.Form2OKButton;
this.CancelButton = this.Form2CancelButton;
...
private void OpenForm3Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form3 testForm = new Form3();
    DialogResult dialogResult = new DialogResult();
    dialogResult = testForm.ShowDialog();
    MessageBox.Show("Form 3 returned: " + Convert.ToString(dialogResult));
}
```

Form 3:

[image: Form 3]

```
...
this.Form3OKButton.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
this.Form3CancelButton.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
...
this.AcceptButton = this.Form3OKButton;
this.CancelButton = this.Form3CancelButton;
```

Steps to reproduce:

- Click "Open Form 2"
- Click "Open Form 3"
- Click "Cancel"

Form 3 closes with DialogResult == Cancel as expected, but Form 2 also closes with DialogResult == Cancel (not expected).

Comment: Mmh, I tried and it [works fine on my machine](http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0128776ff992970c-pi). We should see the whole (real) code to understand the problem. You can use http://pastebin.com/ to paste long pieces of code...

Comment: I have pasted the code here: http://pastebin.com/Dj81gAze

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**EDIT :**

the problem is this one (file: `Form2.Designer.cs`):

```
this.OpenForm3Button.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
```

when you click the `OpenForm3Button`, after the end of the `OpenForm3Button_Click` event handler, the `form.DialogResult` is automatically set to `Cancel` and it is closed.

Reset the `DialogResult` property of `OpenForm3Button` and it will work as expected :)

Comment: No idea how that got set. The weird thing is that it did that in my main project and did the same thing in the hello world one that I set up. I must've made the same mistake both times. Works perfectly now. Thanks very much. I will check for things like that more carefully next time.

Comment: @WarrenBlumenow: If you added the cancel button first, and then copied it (using CTRL-C or CTRL-mousedrag) to create the open button, all the properties of the former are copied in the latter. It happens very often. :)

Comment: Oh, wow. Seems I had this bug because I first set a CancelButton on the form, and then copied that button to make a second button. It seems setting the form's CancelButton automatically set the button's DialogResult. Good to know.

Comment: @Nyerguds I've just discovered that if you dbl-click on the `CancelButton` property of your form in VS, with the aim of cycling through the available buttons until you get to the one you want, it will apply `DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel` to *all* the button you've cycled through.  A big bug indeed.